# Memory issue with get_posts( ) function

Tags: get-posts

I got a fatal error in existing code, when I debug deeper I found that it was coming from bellow line.

```
get_posts( array("posts_per_page"=>-1) );
```

Can anyone explain why is that and how to overcome it?

Error :

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /var/www/web0/html/blog/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 2204
```

Comment: How many posts do you have, as your query fails due to it being to big. I suspect that you have more than 2000 posts you are trying to query

Comment: its about 750 posts

Comment: I suspect that they are quite large. Why do you need to query so many posts at once

Comment: actually I found it in Redux framework which I faced the issue with that. https://github.com/reduxframework/redux-framework/blob/master/ReduxCore/framework.php --- line 951

Comment: Then you should contact the relevant developer about this issue

Comment: Also you could try upping your PHP `memory_limit` to eg "256M", either directly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061917/ini-setmemory-limit-in-php-5-3-3-is-not-working-at-all or via WP_MEMORY_LIMIT http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Increasing_memory_allocated_to_PHP

Answer (score 4):

Running a no limit query is very likely the cause of your memory issues. So you might want to change your query.

If still you need to do this way, you can use the `fields` option, it returns post IDs only and will save a lot of memory usage - example below:

```
$your_query = get_posts(
    array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'fields'         => 'ids',
    )
);
```

Comment: what if need more fields like `post_title` ?

Comment: even with this , it is giving the same results

Comment: The `fields` attribute doesn't change what you can return on your Query - it will just optimize to use less memory. If you're still having problems with that, you need to reduce the number of posts per page by using a pagination, otherwise your server will not be able to list all your 750 posts.

Answer (score 1):

If your circumstances require getting all posts, try adding `'cache_results' => false` to the array of arguments.  So, this.

```
$your_query = get_posts(
    array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'cache_results'  => false,
    )
);
```

That tells `WP_Query` to NOT cache the results, according to this line in `wp-includes/class-wp-query.php`:

```
if ( $q['cache_results'] )
    update_post_caches($this->posts, $post_type, $q['update_post_term_cache'], $q['update_post_meta_cache']);
```

That caching, though it can be a big help for speed if you happen to query the same post multiple times in the same request, is a memory hog and could well be the source of the memory error.

Comment: Note it is possible to disable adding posts to cache for other calls too, such as `get_post()` (which does not have such option as `cache_results` like `get_posts()`) by issuing the `wp_suspend_cache_addition( true );` command before. Consider calling `wp_suspend_cache_addition( false );` when done with the critical part of the code, to allow caching for other code that runs later, if any.